# What regulatory hurdles do I need to conform to to sell my products?

Tags: regulations

I have products that involve some simple resistors and diodes etc that plug into the microphone jack of a mobile phone (they are sensors).

What regulatory hurdles must I cross in order to sell on eBay to 'test the market'?

The Low Voltage Directive isn't applicable because its below 50V (the voltages are phone voltages).

Someone suggested I can 'self-certify' BS-EN 60950 - The Information Technology Standard.  But my 'devices' are much simpler than that would normally be applied to.

Any ideas?

Comment: What regulations have you seen other similar products comply with?

Comment: And I guess that the answer is different depending on your target country(ies).

Comment: Target country is UK.  I think I will go to Maplin or PC world and see what similar products are complying with

Comment: Are there any components on your products that could produce clock-like signals? Are there any clock-like signals coming out of the mobile phone and through your board traces? If yes, the product might be an unintentional transmitter and RF testing might be in order. You don't mention anything about any batteries but if you have one, there is an agency you need to notify and they supposedly tell recycling centres across Europe how to remove the batteries for recycling. You can usually self-certify for everything else. Have a look [here](https://www.gov.uk/ce-marking) and have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

In the US, if your device has any chip in it than runs at above 1.705MHz, you need to have it tested to verify that any unintended radio wave output is below acceptable levels.  If you only really have passive components, you may be able to sell without having your device pass a verification test.

Here is a [good article](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/398) on the topic.